Powershell Remove Cim-Instance Based on Last Login
I am able to output a command into a variable
$logins=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile | Sort-Object -Property LastLogon -Descending | Select-Object -Property * -First 20 | Where-Object {$_.LastLogon -match "(\d{14})"} | Foreach-Object { New-Object PSObject -Property @{ Name=$_.Name;LastLogon=[datetime]::ParseExact($matches[0], "yyyyMMdd", $null)}}

I get this output when $logins is entered into powershell
LastLogon            Name
---------            ----
5/8/2024 1:44:08 PM  Domain\User1
5/8/2024 11:54:31 AM Domain\User2
5/8/2024 11:54:22 AM Domain\User3
5/7/2024 6:52:06 PM  Local\Administrator
4/17/2024 3:21:03 PM Domain\User4
3/4/2024 6:23:11 PM  Domain\User5
1/25/2024 9:20:42 AM Domain\User6

I am trying to remove users based on their last login. Currently I am struggling with the ForEach command. The error I am getting is output to pipeline must not be empty. Which means my first command has no output.
Foreach ($name in $logins) { Where $_.LastLogon -lt (get-date).adddays(-30)} | Remove-CimInstance -Verbose -Confirm:$true `

I have found the lastusetime and lastwritetime on pruning out old profiles unreliable as it will remove profiles that are still currently being used. LastLoginTime using Get-WmiObject is more reliable data to remove old profiles.
I have tried to change the LastLogin variable in the foreach to $LastLogin. I have also tried Where and Where-Object. I dont know what else I can change in this ForEach for it to work.

I do not see how you get those results from the first pipeline. LastLogon is a [datetime] and I do not seem to get it to `-match '(\d{14})'.
